# Visual Studio no longer associated with application crashes

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crash, debugging, windows-vista

When I first installed Visual Studio 2008 on my machine, crashes from applications would present me with a dialog to debug the application in Visual Studio.  This was perfect.

Recently however my Visual Studio installation has become unassociated with application crashes.  Instead I get a dialog which attempts to file the application crash report to Microsoft.  This is very frustrating, as in many cases I do not have time to manually attach Visual Studio as a debugger prior to the application crash.

I do not know why this behaviour has changed, but does anyone know how to reassociate Visual Studio with application crashes?

Comment: I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio, and this did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the association went away, but maybe try [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8kf6y2a.aspx) to fix it:

To enable/disable Just-In-Time debugging

1. On the Tools menu, click Options.
2. In the Options dialog box, select the Debugging folder.
3. In the Debugging folder, select the Just-In-Time page.
4. In the Enable Just-In-Time debugging of these types of code box, select or clear the relevant program types: Managed, Native, or Script. (To disable Just-In-Time debugging, once it has been enabled, you must be running with Administrator privileges. Enabling Just-In-Time debugging sets a registry key, and Administrator privileges are required to change that key.)
5. Click OK.

Comment: Hm, these options were not available to me.  Perhaps because I'm using the Express C++ edition.

Comment: @pauldoo According to the link I showed Just In Time Debugging is not available in any of the Express Editions of Visual Studio. Did you previously have Standard or Pro or higher?

Comment: This particular machine has only ever had the express editions installed.  I must simply be mistaken when I believed that attaching to crashed applications worked before (because as you point out this feature is not present in the Express editions).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround.

If I click the button to show the crash report details, there is a ".mdmp" file mentioned.  I can copy this to a safe location prior to dismissing the dialog, then open this minidump in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat related to this topic: There is an explanation on how to entirely remove crash dialogs (even the ones not related to Visual Studio) in this [link](http://blog.thejaywalker.net/2008/05/disabling-application-crash-dialog-box.html).

I mention it because i found this StackOverflow question while looking for an answer to that one.